# Can I use a whole uncut green pepper that I accidentally froze or is it garbage?

Tags: freezing

I accidentally froze a whole uncut green pepper. I haven't tried anything with it except take it out of freezer. Is this still usable or is it now garbage?

Answer (score 9):

It is certainly still safe to use.

Freezing vegetables will cause the the texture to soften, so it wouldn't provide a very enjoyable crunch, depending on how you plan on using it.

It would be well suited for use in something like a pasta sauce, stew or chili.

Comment: You can also use it for making stock (where you'd throw away the spent vegetables).  I keep a bag in my freezer of vegetables that have gotten a bit sad but not spoiled, parsley stocks, etc. to use when making stock.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use it.

As renesis wrote, the texture will change; so it will much better cooked than raw.

Chop it up and use it in a pasta sauce or a soup, sauce or stew.

I'd do a sofrito with it as a base for a lot of things.